# Why is Aomine so dark-skinned?

Tags: kuroko-no-basket

[image]

As you can see above, Aomine is awfully dark-skinned compared to all the other Japanese characters in Kuroko no Basuke. Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

[Aomine](http://kurokonobasuke.wikia.com/wiki/Daiki_Aomine) being dark-skinned is to show that he used to play street basketball a lot. Unlike indoor basketball, where the players are not subject to direct sunlight, street basketball is played outdoor. Since Aomine used to play street basketball a lot, which can be seen from his playing style, his skin got darker. Also notice that although his skin is dark, he is not as dark-skinned as Papa "Otou-san" Mbaye.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the author wanted a "black" character in the story as a stereotype of being the "best basketball player" but still wanted him to be Japanese, so he is a little lighter than Papa who is African. Another Black Japanese guy is Nebuya on the Rakuzan team who is the same color as Aomine. The reason they aren’t as dark as Papa is because they’re dark-skinned Japanese people while Papa is literally a black person.

Note if you look at the official colored manga for Aomine, Nebuya and Papa they're relatively similarly as dark. Granted papa is still the darkest but not by much.

Comment: Welcome to Anime and Manga. with the first part to your answer do you have any sources backing it up?

Answer (score 2):

Black people have different shades of skin color. So it doesn't have to be to look Japanese. Taiga too played a lot outside but he doesn't have the same skin color which means that Aomine is naturally dark colored.